# Razor Pages - Obtener item Seleccionado en Control select

Tags: c#, select, razor, binding

Tengo un form que tiene un control tipo select, los items son llenados con una propiedad tipo List de la página llamada _dispositivosList, tiene el tag helper asp-for asignado a otra propiedad tipo int llamada _dispositivoID y la propiedad name del control select tabien tiene asignado ese nombre, en el evento onchange ejecuto un método para filtrar un listado, hasta aquí funciona, pero al presionar un botón ejecuto otra función donde necesito el item seleccionado, pero en este momento ya no está vinculado la propiedad _dispositivoID al item seleccionado, cómo puedo obtener dicho valor con código C#, no JavaScript, o si es con JavaScript cómo lo asigno a una propiedad del Modelo de la página?

El control select es este:

```html
            <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="_dispositivoID" asp-for="_dispositivoID"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model._dispostivosList, nameof(Model._dispositivo.Num), nameof(Model._dispositivo.Nombre)))"
                    id="_dispositivoID" class="input-text-col text-s"></select>
```

Las propiedades del Modelo de la página están así:

```
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public List<ModelDb.Dispositivo> _dispostivosList { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int _dispositivoID { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet =true)]
    public ModelDb.Dispositivo _dispositivo { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo

Aunque no es exactamente lo que buscaba pero funciona... lo que hice fué

- Gardar en **`TempData`** el valor del item seleccionado

Y como necesito que este valor no se elimine al leerlo

- Usé el método **`Keep`** después de leer el **`TempData`**

> y así puedo seguir leyendo este valor en otras funciones de la página